# Альт код валидация в java

Tags: java

Добрый день, мне необходимо проверить строку на наличие альт кода, например ☺ или чего то такого, пользователь не должен вставлять такие символы в имя.

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения

Answer (score 1):

**[a-Z0-9]***  - это соответствует выражению в котором будут только латинские буквы разного регистра и цифры, остальное отсеет.